# VB script sometimes return certain missing file? Extracting of files takes too long?

Tags: windows, vbscript, iexpress

I have this VB script which I later compiled it together with some dll files using IExpress. Sometimes when a user run this script it will return an error message stating that certain dll file is not found.

From what I under is, the installer which is created when using IExpress will extract the files into a temporary folder at %temp%\IXP000.TMP. I am suspecting that sometimes the script does not run long enough to allow all the dll files to be extract to the temporary folder before executing the script.

Are there any ways to ensure all the files are extracted before running the script in the installer?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Can you please clarify – you are using IExpress to bundle some VBScript and a some `.dll` files? Which `.dll` file is not found? Perhaps you can share your SED file with us.

Comment: Hi @fission,

The  error of file not found does not target any single dll directly, it seems to be random and sometimes it does not even have an error which leads me to think that it is the extracting process not being completed when the script runs.

Comment: Sounds odd. It's hard to believe that the “install program” is being launched before the extract is complete. But there's an easy way to check: use [Process Monitor](https://live.sysinternals.com/procmon.exe) to see when the files are extracted _vs_ when your install program starts. There might even be a clue in there about why the DLL is not found.